# cakephp multiple select not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.2, validates-associated

I have two tables 'businesses' and `business_categories` and their association is like

**BusinessesTable.php**

```
$this->hasMany('SellerBusinessCategories', [
    foreignKey => 'business_id'
]);
```

and I have to input multiple categories to `business_categories` table along with `businesses`.

This is how the input field is in `add.ctp` view

```
<?= $this->Form->input('seller_business_categories._category_ids', [
        'options' => $categories,
        'multiple' => true,
        'type' => 'select',
        'class' => 'form-control select2',
        'label' => false
    ])
?>
```

but this is giving error as

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
1364 Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value in business_categories
```

and form is not submitting. Removing `multiple => true` and replacing `business_categories._category_ids` to `business.category_id` is working fine.

Is there anything missing ?

> Edit 2

**SellerBusinessesController.php**

```
public function add()
{
    $sellerBusiness = $this->SellerBusinesses->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $sellerBusiness->seller_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $sellerBusiness = $this->SellerBusinesses->patchEntity($sellerBusiness, $this->request->data, [
          'associated' => [
            'SellerBusinessCategories'
          ]
        ]);
        if ($this->SellerBusinesses->save($sellerBusiness)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The seller business has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The seller business could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $categories = $this->SellerBusinesses->SellerBusinessCategories->Categories->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $sellers = $this->SellerBusinesses->Sellers->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('sellerBusiness', 'sellers', 'categories'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['sellerBusiness']);

}
```

> **on debugging : debug($this->request->data), gives**

```
'seller_business_categories' => [
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\SellerBusinessCategory) {

    (int) 0 => '1',
    (int) 1 => '2',
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        (int) 0 => true,
        (int) 1 => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'SellerBusinessCategories'

}
```

],

Comment: add your controller code

Comment: have added code for controller in edit 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that your query to get list was not clear enough

```
<select>
 <option value="$AAA">$BBB</option>
</select>
```

You need to get keyField as the value ($AAA) and the valueField as text view ($BBB).

This is my example for getting the city list for my Dropdown list.

```
public function getcity()
{
    //Get model MCities
    $MCities = TableRegistry::get('MCities');

    $query = $MCities->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'id', //consider this line
        'valueField' => 'city',//consider this line
        // 'order' => 'city'
    ]);

    //Add the default zero is "Select city"
    $data_init = ['0'=>'Select city'];

    $data = $data_init + $query->toArray();
    return $data;
}
```

Hope it help !

**EDIT #2**

Following my code. When I debug it will show as below (There are Vietnamese cities)

This is my database.
[image]

And this is my debug after query.

```
[
    (int) 0 => 'Select city',
    (int) 1 => 'Thành phố Hà Nội',
    (int) 2 => 'Tỉnh Hà Giang',
    (int) 3 => 'Tỉnh Cao Bằng',
    (int) 4 => 'Tỉnh Bắc Kạn',
    (int) 5 => 'Tỉnh Tuyên Quang',
    (int) 6 => 'Tỉnh Lào Cai',
    (int) 7 => 'Tỉnh Điện Biên',
    (int) 8 => 'Tỉnh Lai Châu',
    (int) 9 => 'Tỉnh Sơn La',
    (int) 10 => 'Tỉnh Yên Bái',
]
```

You have to define to select box knows that where is the id (value) and where is the text. Because of maybe in your table will have many columns (fields).

Comment: please see the result of debug($this->request->data). I don't think the problem is with category ids

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my mention about. Because of your showed error is "1364 Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value in business_categories" so I think that my ideas is right. Please check out my EDIT #2 for more clear.